# How to convert an array from firestore to string to display in a viewholder textview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am puzzled as to why this is not working. I have an array (daysOfWeek) inside a document in Firestore that I need to display in a view holder in a recyclerview. Strings, ints, longs etc. that I am extracting from the document are all fine but I cannot figure out how to convert an arraylist into a string. Just for some context, the array contains the user selected days of the week and I need the corresponding textview to show all of the selected days of the week.

Here is a snippet from my adapter code:

```
public class MealPlanDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MealPlanDetailsAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder> {

    private Context adapterContext;
    private ArrayList<MealplanDetails> mealplanDetailsArrayList;

    private final static String TAG = MealPlanDetailsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public MealPlanDetailsAdapter(Context adapterContext, ArrayList<MealplanDetails> mealplanDetailsArrayList) {
        this.mealplanDetailsArrayList = mealplanDetailsArrayList;
        this.adapterContext = adapterContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MealPlanDetailsAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(adapterContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mealplan_card, viewGroup, false);
        return new MealPlanDetailsViewHolder(view);
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MealPlanDetailsAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder mpDetailsViewHolder, int position) {

        // Set days of week

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object day : mealplanDetailsArrayList.get(position).getDaysOfWeek())
        {
            stringBuilder.append(day.toString());
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
        }

        String finalDays = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "days of the week:" + finalDays);
        mpDetailsViewHolder.tvDaysOfWeek.setText(finalDays);

        // Set restaurant
        // Set menu items
    }

   class MealPlanDetailsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public tvDaysOfWeek

        public MealPlanDetailsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvDaysOfWeek = itemView.findViewById(R.id.days_week);

        }
    }
```

My recycler is working fine. No issues with the adapter. But its this array that is causing problems. The stack trace is as follows:

```
Process: com.healthplan, PID: 20051
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.healthplan.MealPlanDetailsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MealPlanDetailsAdapter.java:65)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with Firestore.  `mpDetailsViewHolder.tvDaysOfWeek` is just null.  That means your line of code that's trying to find the TextView is wrong:

```
tvDaysOfWeek = itemView.findViewById(R.id.days_week);
```

You'll have to figure out where that TextView is and identify it correctly.